# Changing text of a TextView throws NullPointer Exception

Tags: java, android, exception, textview

I'm just following the basic tutorial on the Android website. However, I'm trying to change a few things just for fun. For instance, instead of creating a runtime `TextView` (as in the tutorial) within the method `onCreate(...)` of the `DisplayMessageActivty` class, I've defined a static `TextView` in the XML layout file because I'd like to show also other things (e.g., a static message as well as the resulting entered message from the main screen). So, in the corresponding XML file of `DisplayMessageActivty` I've defined the `TextView` and other stuff as:

```
[...]

<TextView android:id="@+id/dynamic_msg"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ciao"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/static_msg"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/times" />

[...]
```

then, I access to that `TextView` in the following way (`onCreate(...)` method of the `DisplayMessageActivty` class):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Get the message from the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // HERE I WANT TO CHANGE THE CONTENT OF THE TEXTVIEW
    TextView dynamicText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dynamic_msg);
    dynamicText.setText(message);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

    // Up button
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

Unfortunately, when I press the `Send` button in the main activity my code throws the following exception:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference`

I've searched on the Internet and the approach adopted in other tutorials looks quite similar, so I cannot understand what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: `setContentView` goes before `findViewById`, otherwise you have no widgets to find

Comment: Argh!!! I didn't know that... thank you so much. If you write your comment as answer I can vote that ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content is not set into the view, the `findviewByid` will return NULL if you do it BEFORE `setContentView`.

move
 `setContentView` BEFORE `findviewByid` and it will work.